# Efficient way to clear selections and select new item in KDE Dolphin in one step?

Tags: kde, gui, dolphin

I prefer KDE's default single click behavior in all cases except the following:

Starting situation:

- I have one or more files (or folders) selected already (from some previous action)
- I want to perform a different action (such as deleting) on a new file

Three steps are required:

- I have to first manually clear the existing selection (such as using escape)
- Then I have to select the new file
- Then I have to perform the action on the file

If I instead used double-click as the default, it would eliminate at least one of those steps. But I want to keep using single click behavior.

**My question is how can I most efficiently clear an existing selection and make a new selection (either files or folders) in one action?**

The suggested method should not rely on right clicking (because the action I want to perform may not be in the context menu). And the method should not mix mouse and keyboard actions -- it should use one or the other for efficiency & simplicity.

Ideally, I want something as simple as the way it would work if I used double-click actions. In that case, a single left mouse click on a new item would clear prior selections and select the new item. How do I achieve that simplicity and efficiency while sticking with single click actions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**With the 'paint' ?**

'Paint' one or more files - it will release the already selected files.

Left click the Dolphin/Konqueror background and move the mouse to draw the section box.

[image]